# Windows 7, Visual Studio 2012, PhoneGap 2.9 - Does it work?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-7, cordova

As the title states, I have Windows 7 with VS 2012 installed.

I'm trying to get PhoneGap/Cordova working by downloading the zip from their website and copying the files to my template directory but I'm getting *lots* of errors:

**Template: Win 7**

There is a missing project subtype - Subtype is unsupported by this installation.

**Template: Win 8 -> Win 7** (don't ask, I don't know)

The file appbar.back.rest.png could not be found within the project templates

The file appbar.close.rest.png could not be found within the project templates

(It goes on to list a whole bunch of png, xaml and wav files)

I've tried using visual studio 2010 but that has it's own issues so I would like to try and get it working in 2012 if I can...

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by missing files within the zipped up Template files copied to the VS template directory;

C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Templates\ProjectTemplates

For instance in my case the images folder was empty. I was able to fix it by downloading the templates again from [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/cordova-wp8) and re-adding the missing files to the CordovaWP8_0_0_0.zip

Comment: Could you be more specific on where do I put missing *.png files in this zip file? I tried to copy them in many places inside of this zip file, and in call cases I was getting the same errors about missing png files.

Comment: If you unpack the contents of the incomplete CordovaWP8_0_0_0.zip template and open up the project file with Visual Studio it will show you all of the missing files which you can then fix. Then simply zip it back up and replace CordovaWP8_0_0_0.zip

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. and here how i solved them.
1) after installing the template file on C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#, i have got following files:

- common-folder
- wp7-folder
- wp8-folder
- CordovaWP7_3_3_0-dev.zip
- CordovaWP8_3_3_0-dev.zip
- createTemplates.bat

after launching the visual studio, i got the same error messages that i don't have png's and some other files.

I found all those files inside the common folder except VERSION. You can find this file inside cordova-wp8-master.zip archive.

after that i just copied all those files into root folder of CordovaWP7_3_3_0-dev.zip archive.

working! :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Oli Gray's solution, the missing plugins can be found [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap). Just navigate to the windows-phone-8 folder, and you'll find that the common folder has most of the missing files.  Add it to the unzipped project, rezip, then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem as above  and I have found some solution.
As per my knowledge   with Windows 7 , Visual Studio 2012, PhoneGap 2.9 does not work because there is no WindowsPhone SDK to create WindowsPhoneApp in visual studio 2012 but we create same with Visual studio 2010 for WindowsPhone 7.x   and  In visual studio 2010 Its done using template. 
 **Steps for Create Project in visual studio 2010:**

- Fist Download WindowsPhoneSDK7 for windows 7  [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27570/)
- After that download  latest version of [Phonegap SDK](http://phonegap.com/download)
- open lib/Windows Phone folder after extracting  downloaded Phpnegap sdk
- In this folder  click on "createTemplates.bat"  file which generate zip file like **CordovaWP7_x_x_x.zip**
- Copy **CordovaWP7_x_x_x.zip** & Paste to  **Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#**
- Now open Visual studio 2010 &  Start new project which shows  **CordovaWP7_x_x_x.zip** Template then project created successfully.